# C data format redoing

Tags: c, arrays

I have data stored as

```
float testdata3[][7] = {
{171032, 0.4448, -0.3032, -0.7655, -1.3428, 13.5803, -73.0743},
{172292, 0.0099, 0.1470, -0.7301, -17.2272, 7.0038, -11.7722},
{173547, 0.0576, 0.1333, -0.8163, -2.7847, -9.5215, 8.1177 },
...
}
```

where I am only interested in the second, third and fourth indexes. How can I create a function where it would return for example first, second and third index as their own table from the testdata I have.

For example

```
testdata_x = {0.4448, 0.099, 0.0576, ...}
testdata_y = {-0.3032, 0.1470, 0.1333, ...}
testdata_z = {-0.7655, -0.7301, -0.8163, ...}
```

Help would be much appreciated. I am trying to read sensor values from test data and im only interested in acceleration values in x, y and z directions.

Comment: You should provide what you have tried so far and tell us where you have problems. Otherwise it looks like a code writing request.

Comment: So the data is already there, right? Why not use it in the way it is stored? Or are you trying to reduce the size of a data file?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post any code so I'm going to be a bit more vague than normal.

If we create an array of 7 elements such as: `int arr[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};`

Accessing the 2nd, third, and 4th elements is as simple as `arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]` respectively.

That should help with gleaning the data from the existing arrays, but as for making your new array. I don't see any reason to use a multidimensional array instead of 3 regular arrays. All you need to do from here is find out the amount of arrays in testData in order to know how much to allocate and you should be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to transpose a matrix? then just iterate in the reverse order

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double arr[][7] = {
        {171032, 0.4448, -0.3032, -0.7655, -1.3428, 13.5803, -73.0743},
        {172292, 0.0099, 0.1470, -0.7301, -17.2272, 7.0038, -11.7722},
        {173547, 0.0576, 0.1333, -0.8163, -2.7847, -9.5215, 8.1177},
    };

    #define ROWS sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]
    #define COLS sizeof arr[0] / sizeof arr[0][0]

    double test[COLS][ROWS]; /* 7 x 3 */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
            test[i][j] = arr[j][i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are looking for but here are several approaches starting from easiest one:

1) You can directly assign a value using indexes to the new array

2) If you need function you can allocate new array inside it assign all
    values and return it from a function

It's supposed that indexes never change for x,y,z.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum
{
    X,
    Y,
    Z
};

float testdata3[][7] = {
    {171032, 0.4448, -0.3032, -0.7655, -1.3428, 13.5803, -73.0743},
    {172292, 0.0099, 0.1470, -0.7301, -17.2272, 7.0038, -11.7722},
    {173547, 0.0576, 0.1333, -0.8163, -2.7847, -9.5215, 8.1177 },
};

float *get_dataa(int coordinate)
{
    float *data;

    switch(coordinate) {
    case X:
        data = malloc(sizeof(float) * 3);
        data[0] = testdata3[0][1];
        data[1] = testdata3[1][1];
        data[2] = testdata3[2][1];

        return data;

    default:
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    /* first way */
    float testdata_X[] = { testdata3[0][1], testdata3[1][1], testdata3[2][1] };
    printf("Test number 1 for X %0.4f, %0.4f, %0.4f\n", testdata_X[0], testdata_X[1], testdata_X[2]);

    /* second */
    float *testdata_xX = get_dataa(X);
    printf("Test number 2 for X %0.4f, %0.4f, %0.4f\n", testdata_xX[0], testdata_xX[1], testdata_xX[2]);
    free(testdata_xX);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> Test number 1 for X 0.4448, 0.0099, 0.0576
>
> Test number 2 for X 0.4448, 0.0099, 0.0576